# Why do we say something is The same (using the article), but we say something is different (no article)?

Tags: articles

We say "the same", but "different" (no article)? A student asked me this question, and I wasn't sure how to answer him. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Funnily enough I can't think of a single sentence where you wouldn't pair the word "same" with the word "the". It's not correct to say "a same"...

Comment: We do say *This is **the same** usage, but that is **a different** usage*. I'd say that's because there's only "one thing" which is ***the*** same, so it can be *specifically* identified. But there are lots of "other, different things", so we use the somewhat vaguer *indefinite* article to reference one of them. Contrast *"I don't want the same thing. I want **the** other one"*, as opposed to *"I want **another** one"*.

Comment: If your student is a non-native speaker, just tell them that this *[same](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/same)* is a pronoun, but *[different](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/different)* is an adjective. If that doesn't work because they have no idea what pronouns and adjectives are, it will be a great time for them to start learning grammar! If that doesn't work because they want to know why one is a pronoun and the other is an adjective, you can pretend to give up and say "It's because", and ask about some oddities in their first language. ;-)

Comment: English is not the only language where this is so. French and Spanish has it too. German does not- there is not article when saying something is the same versus saying something is different. Those are the only languages with which I am familiar (though rusty). I want to think it is a Latin versus Germanic/Teutonic thing and tied to the origins of the words- different is Latin and same is Norse. Just same "same difference" and you can use the article for both. ; )

Comment: @DamkerngT. - That should be an answer; you've unlocked the mystery. The counterpart to _different_ is the adjective _alike_: _These two cars are different, but those two cars are alike_.

Answer (score 5):

Because *the same* is short for *the same {noun}*.

Quite a few modifiers can function as nouns if *the* is put in front of them, with the "real" noun being implied if there is one.  Use of the article "the" signals that it's a noun (pronoun in the case of *same*).

Of course, if you use *a/an*, the noun needs to be explicit.

> The sick [people] among us must be helped.
>
> The sinful [followers] must be called to atone for their sins.
>
> Don't throw out the bad [whatever] with the good [whatever].
>
> Please do the needful [actions].

Comment: Just to note that I'd never heard the phrase "please do the needful" until I joined ELL - this is after 55 years as a native speaker - & it still sounds **so** not English.

Comment: @Tetsujin I still haven't encountered "Please do the needful."

Comment: What does your answer have to do with the OP's question? E.g. *"The boys are the same"* versus *"The boys are different"*. Notice that the PCs can't be expanded into NPs, e.g. \* _"The boys are the same boys"_.

Comment: "The boys are the same person?" or "The boys are the same child?"

Comment: But that's not what "the same" means here; it means that the boys have similar attributes, not that they are the same boys/persons. -- That is, "the same" seems to be an adjective phrase (not a NP).

Comment: Ahh ... good point there.  I did not consider that.

Comment: I suspect that the "the" here, in "the same", might be a bit uglier to explain. There are some "the"s that don't function as a determiner, but rather, they function as a modifier. This might be one of those cases (and there might be some historical stuff involved here too, maybe).

Comment: @Tetsujin please visit India! (copy: Ben) :P

Comment: @F.E. Do you think *the same* might be one word? We don't seem to be able to modify *same*. [In the phrase *the very same* the meaning of *same* is different. Compare "they are the same" and "they are the very same".]

Comment: @Araucaria That could be one way to treat it. The expression appears to function differently at times (and so, perhaps maybe two different expressions). Consider *"The boys are the same"*, where "the same" seems comparable to an AdjP (not a NP), where maybe it acts as a single grammatical word, similar to *"The boys are tall"*; ...

Comment: @Araucaria (cont) and compare it to *"The boys who took your dog and the boys who damaged your car are the same (boys)"*, where "the same" might not be a single whole constituent/phrase, but rather two separate elements (Det + Adj) of a NP (fused head). But I'm talking off the top of my head, with no daily coffee yet. *CGEL* discusses this, if I recall correctly. It's a messy topic, imo, all the different uses of "the". Maybe someone who has the time and resources might explain this.